# Javascript files not loaded for some Mac users (error 403 Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently when we updated our website really strange things happen.

- All files in CSS, JSS folders return 403 error FORBIDDEN (website.com/css/style.css CANNOT be accessed eventhough website.com can)
- Copied a file style.css to a new folder named "newcss" and the file website.com/newcss/style.css CAN BE accessed
- Apparently login.aspx and webconfig files were somehow copied mistakenly by developer to multiple folders such as css and js folders
- So, CSS folder has a pair of login.aspx and webconfig files and so does js folder
- Problem solved when login.aspx and/or webconfig file in that folder were deleted

Now, some Mac users are complaining that js files were not loaded properly on their browsers although it's working well in my Mac.

Screenshot of the error.[403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVsGh.png)

It is working well in my Chrome and Safari and I believe many website visitors are not affected too.

The JS files are important because it has functions adding items to shopping cart.

Windows Server 2012, IIS8

Anyone experienced this before?